# Portrait to Landscape - Common Extra Space Fillers?

Tags: portrait, landscape, background, backdrops

I have a lot of portrait photos that I would like to make landscape.  They're not high-res enough to just crop out a landscape section of the photo for my purposes.

What are common techniques and tools for filling the edges of portrait photos to make them landscape?

Comment: I'm not sure if there _are_ common tools or techniques, because I don't think it's a common thing to do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Elendi commented, this sort of thing isn't that common.

What we do see a lot where someone wants to place a portrait photo in a landscape frame is associating it with a comment, a piece of poetry, some background etc.

The most common seems to be having text to one side of the photo, either left or right, but I have on occasion seen text placed on both sides, with the photo centred.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the pictures, a good option might be to do [diptychs or triptychs](http://digital-photography-school.com/diptychs-triptychs-5-prime-examples).